# Failed to Rebuild Indexes[Underlying DBMS error]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoprocessing, oracle-dbms

I am trying to rebuild indexes on a feature class and standalone table within ArcMap 10.2.1 and its giving an error which says:

> Unable to rebuild indexes[Underlying DBMS error]

All other indexes rebuild fine except on this feature class and standalone table. The two have no relationship with each other.I use an Oracle database.

I've tried researching this error but nothing is helpful.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to provide more details -- What exact version of Oracle? What geometry storage type? How many features in the table? What does the Oracle alert log report? Is the tablespace near capacity?

Comment: Repair geometry and try to rebuild indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle version 11g. ESRI geometry storage type....Evidently, i had more than 11 indexes on the table and I was running into the following bug:

> NIM098099: The Rebuild Indexes tool fails when 11 or more indexes are
>   present on a single Oracle feature class. Unable to rebuild indexes
>   for dataset (failed to execute).

Deleting some indexes until they were 11 , rebuilding, and then re-adding the indexes back would be a sufficient workaround via a script.